# Inserting into mysql table with archive engine "duplicate key" error

Tags: mysql, archive

I am trying to archive some files using mysql archive engine. I am using this query to insert file contents:

```
insert into test_table (id,arch) values (123,'FILE_CONTENT')
```

After inserting 2 records, I get "duplicate key" error from mysql for a key that doesn't exist in the table. I checked it like 5 times but the record is not there. I selected count(*) for the duplicate id and the result is 0.

I checked the same code with an innodb engine and it works fine. Can anyone tell me what the problem is with the archive engine?

EDIT:

My table info is

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `arch` mediumtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=ARCHIVE AUTO_INCREMENT=100175977 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: Please post your table definition. This shouldn't be. Is there a trigger on this table?

Comment: I edited my question, and no trigger on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have discovered a bug in the `ARCHIVE` engine. The insertion seems to be failing as soon as you try to insert a record with a value for an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column smaller than the `AUTO_INCREMENT` property of the table.

This works fine:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table1 (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=ARCHIVE AUTO_INCREMENT=123; -- notice the AUTO_INCREMENT value

INSERT INTO test_table1 (id) value (123); -- ok
```

But this fails with "Duplicate key":

```
CREATE TABLE test_table2 (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=ARCHIVE AUTO_INCREMENT=124; -- notice the AUTO_INCREMENT value

INSERT INTO test_table2 (id) value (123); -- duplicate key
```

MyISAM and InnoDB do not exhibit this behaviour, and I can find no reference to this in the docs. I would file a bug at MySQL if I were you (verified under [v5.5.6](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c47fb) and [v5.5.32](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c47fb)).

Comment: I'm not very good at reading C++, but it seems that the code that handles unicity checks has been purposedly nerfed for performance reasons (read from [line 982](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/5.7/view/head:/storage/archive/ha_archive.cc)). Maybe someone who knows better could verify.

Comment: According to http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47662/inserting-into-mysql-table-with-archive-engine-duplicate-key-error, it seems like it is not possible to have an indexed column in an archive table.  The only way is to use auto increment which should not be set during insert (or just use 0).

Comment: This answer is self-contradictory, despite its quoting a relevant manual excerpt ("The AUTO_INCREMENT column can have either a unique or nonunique index"). It also contains dubious information such as "*[inserting a row with an explicit value for an AUTO_INCREMENT column]* would produce a normal Duplicate Key for other Storage Engines" (same insertions succeed with InnoDB). It has nothing to do with `AUTO_INCREMENT` but with the `PRIMARY KEY`. It is true, however, that an `ARCHIVE` table is not meant to be read frequently. It is, as the name suggests, an space-efficient *storage* solution.

Comment: IMHO, the remaining questions are: 1. Why did you choose this engine at all? If you plan on **reading** from this table on a frequent basis, then it may not be the best choice. 2. Do you wish to understand the internal mechanisms of MySQL? Then believe me, this is most probably a bug. It should probably be regarded as a documentation bug: the limitation we found should be documented, rather than fixed, because the use case does not seems to fit the purpose of the `ARCHIVE` engine.

Comment: @AliBZ FYI this bug has been reported to MySQL. See [this bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37182), in particular, the test case advised by Shane Bester on 22 Dec 2008 20:43 almost exactly describes your situation.

Comment: I am keeping my archives on the hard drive now. Now I planned to store them in mysql instead. That is why I am choosing to use archive engine, otherwise, the table will get really big as the archive engine compresses the data.